# Idiomatic way to deserialize a JSON to a POJO of unknown type at compile time

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, gson, deserialization

I am working on a server-side service in Java. When a user connects to the service, a new session is opened. Afterwards the user communicates with the service by sending JSON messages:

```
{
    type: A,
    body: {
        ...
    }
}
```

Where "type" defines 1:1 which specific POJO should "body" be deserialized to.

So far, so simple. Sure. An enum assigning one to the other should suffice. Problem is... I then need to pass such a deserialized POJO to the user's Session for processing. The Session is stateful, with many possible states, with every state knowing how to process only it's own few specific messages.

I managed to "solve" this issue with:

```
interface MessageType<TConsumer> {
    Combo<?, TConsumer> combo();
}

class Combo<T, TConsumer> {
    private final Class<T> clazz;
    private final BiConsumer<TConsumer, T> biConsumer;

    ...
    // accessors
}

class Wombo<T, Tconsumer> {
    private final T body;
    private final BiConsumer<TConsumer, T> biConsumer;

    void consume(TConsumer consumeBy) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Where:

T - is the type of the message body

TConsumer - is a session state which knows how to process only specific message bodies

MessageType - is an interface implemented by enums, which know which specific message bodies are allowed in which specific session states. As well as if we ARE in a given sate AND a given message comes in - what should we do with it. Every session state possesses it's own enum.

Combo - is a helper class we pass along with a raw json to a deserializer which in consequence produces an instance of Wombo.

Wombo - which is holding the message body, as well as knows how to process it when we pass it an instance of the session state.

Phew... This seems ridiculously overengineered (a.k.a. needlessly complex) for what I only presume is a very common business need.

**TLDR: Is there an idiomatic way in Java to deserialize a JSON to a POJO depending on the context of another object? And then to process said POJO in said context in a type-safe manner?**

Thanks in advance guys! :)

P.S. It seems to me this would be fairly straightforward if Java allowed parameterized enums. Then again, maybe using an enum here is a design error of it's own?

Answer (score 0):

The best ways that I know to serialize Object to JSON and deserialize JSON to Object is ti use Gson. It's a good tool for that job